# async/await inside a reduce method doesnt map my object properly- JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, async-await

I have an array of objects and I would like to create an object where each 'id' property in the object fetches a 'title' using an API.

This is my code:

```js
const data = [{

    "id": 7,
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
  }
]

const result = data.reduce(async(a, c, i) => {
  const jsonData = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${c.id}`)
  const resolvedJSONData = await jsonData.json();
  console.log( resolvedJSONData.title)
  return {
    ...a,
    [`button-${i+1}`]: resolvedJSONData.title
  }
}, {})

result.then(res => console.log(res))
```

Expected result:

```
{"button-1": "illo expedita consequatur quia in", "button-2": "et doloremque nulla"}
```

Why does the first title get mapped to the second button? Please advice.

Comment: reduce does not support async functions. All it will see is a function that returns a promise. You probably want to use `map` and `Promise.all`

Comment: @FredStark I was following this tutorial: https://advancedweb.hu/how-to-use-async-functions-with-array-reduce-in-javascript/

Comment: @a2441918 then why aren't you `await`-ing `a`? The tutorial is quite explicit that the last value would be a promise. You're instead treating it as an object.

Comment: @a2441918 maybe you should follow the rest of that tutorial

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is await your accumulator to get the correct results. Since your reduce is returning a promise, so does your accumulator.

```js
const data = [{

    "id": 7,
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
  }
]

const result = data.reduce(async(a, c, i) => {
  const jsonData = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${c.id}`)
  const resolvedJSONData = await jsonData.json();
  return {
    ...(await a),
    [`button-${i+1}`]: resolvedJSONData.title
  }
}, Promise.resolve({}))

result.then(res => console.log(res))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `reduce` with something async, the accumulator should be a Promise that resolves to the half-formed array, a Promise that you wait for the resolution of before continuing on:

```js
const data = [{

    "id": 7,
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
  }
]

const result = data.reduce(async(a, c, i) => {
  const resultsSoFar = await a;
  const jsonData = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${c.id}`)
  const resolvedJSONData = await jsonData.json();
  return {
    ...resultsSoFar,
    [`button-${i+1}`]: resolvedJSONData.title
  }
}, Promise.resolve({}))

result.then(res => console.log(res))
```

But using `Promise.all` would be much more appropriate here, it'll finish more quickly:

```js
const data = [{

    "id": 7,
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
  }
]

Promise.all(
  data.map((c, i) =>
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${c.id}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(result => ({ result, i }))
  )
)
  .then((results) => {
    const obj = Object.fromEntries(
      results.map(({ result, i }) => ([
        `button-${i+1}`, // key in new object
        result.title // value in new object
      ]))
    );
    console.log(obj);
  });
```